# PHP Email Manager That Lets Me Read Emails?

Tags: php, email

Guys!

I have searched Google (even Bing, that's how desperate I am) looking for a free PHP script that allows me to read emails from it and (maybe) send newsletters. This is getting annoying, so please help me out. Note that when people send an email to support@mysite.com, the email will be sent straight to that script for me or other staff members to read, kind of like how WHMCS does it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really on topic here I'm afraid. But - what do you mean by "read" exactly? Do you want the script to process the message? What should it do? If it's just about you receiving the mail, would a simple forwarding not be much easier?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I mean like when you go into Google you see an inbox and you can send and read emails. That's all I want to do :(

Comment: Can you at least tell us if you have root access on the server, which OS and what MTA?

Comment: Using WHM and cPanel you can forward emails to a pipe to program interface where you can read emails.  If youre looking for a mail client, try using roudcube or Outlook.

Comment: @Aragon0 I am using cPanel on Linux. I don't want to use Outlook, I want to use a program that allows me to read every email at once. :)

Comment: Well, then look at SyntaxLAMP's answer. You can pipe your mails to PHP and then store them in a MySQL database. Afterwards you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: @Aragon0 how in the hell do I do that? Could you help me :(

Comment: Then you need to tell me what exactly you are trying to do and what are you goals. Do you want to read the mails programmatically, and what should finnally happen to them?

Comment: @Aragon0 do you have Skype? Mine is owenbick. If not, can we find a different way to talk more efficiently?

Comment: @Owen lorenz.brun, you should be able to text my directly without adding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What platform? I know a good way using Postfix on Linux, but you need root access to the box: [Here](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail)
That's for a filter, but you can do whatever you want with the PHP script, for later reading I'd store the messages in a database or in the local filesystem.

For sending I recommend using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) with Sendmail transport and Postfix as delivering server.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Setup an email pipe to program in cPanel
In cPanel (not WHM), go to the Forwarders icon under Mail.  Click Add Forwarder.  Enter an email address that will receive mail.  Click Advanced Options.  Select Pipe to Program.  Enter the absolute path to your PHP script after calling PHP.  Like, /usr/local/bin/php home/myUserName/script.php  So, the path to PHP, then the path to the script.

Step 2:  Create a script to receive email

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);
$lines2 = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$response = "";
$sendmail = "";
$splittingheaders = true;


$date = date("n/j/Y");
$datecode = strtotime($date);

//we have processed the headers and can start adding the lines to $message.
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }

    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}
```

Now you are left with variables $from, $message, and $subject that contain all of the information from the email.  There are lots of ways to parse out the contents of an email message, but the above has worked for me in the past.

Step 3:  Create a database that will store the messages
You should create a MySQL database with tables like messages, attachments, etc to store the contents of the messages.  There are tons of tutorials and help for creating and managing databases with PHP and PHPMyAdmin.

Step 4:  Create a PHP program that will display and manage emails like other mail clients do, with the functionality of viewing multiple emails, as you require.

Now, please note that you will have to do some work on your own.  Without being paid, I wouldn't bet on anyone here writing the whole thing for you.  You should get started with learning PHP and SQL statements and start programming this on your own.  Then, as problems arise or you are stuck, we would be glad to help!